# jQuery input_token + Rails4 + Simple form gem

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have 2 models `sprofile` and `skills`

In `sprofile.rb`

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :skills ,dependent: :destroy

def skill_tokens=(tokens)
    self.skill_ids  = Skill.ids_from_tokens(tokens)         
end
```

In `sprofiles_controller.rb`

```
def sprofile_params
  params.require(:sprofile).permit(:first_name, :last_name,{:skill_ids => []})
end
```

In `skill.rb`

```
class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_and_belongs_to_many :sprofiles


 def self.tokens(query)

    skills = where("name like ?" , "%#{query}%")
    if skills.empty?
        [{id: "<<<#{query}>>>" , name: "New: \"#{query}\""}]
    else
        skills
    end
 end

 def self.ids_from_tokens(tokens)
    tokens.gsub!(/<<<(.+?)>>>/) { create!(name: $1).id  }
    tokens.split(',')
 end
end
```

In `skills_controller.rb`

```
class SkillsController < ApplicationController
 def index
    @skills = Skill.order(:name)
    respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json {render json: @skills.tokens(params[:q])}
    end
 end

 def show
    @skill = Skill.find_by(:id)
 end
end
```

In `application.js`

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery.purr
//= require jquery.tokeninput
//= require jquery-ui
//= require autocomplete-rails
//= require jquery.raty
//= require ratyrate
//= require best_in_place
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

In `sprofile views`

```
<%= simple_form_for(@sprofile) do |f| %>
 <%= f.collection_select :level_id, Level.all,  :id, :name , {prompt: "choose a level"} %>
 <%= f.input :document, as: :file %>
 <%= f.input :avatar, as: :file %>
 <%= f.input :contact_no , :placeholder => "123-456-7899" %>

 <%= f.association :skills, input_html: { class: 'token' }%>
     <div class="form-actions">
 <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
 <% end %>
```

in `sprofiles.js.coffee`

```
jQuery ->
   $('.token').tokenInput "/skills.json"
```

**It works fine but does not save the data into skills_ids**

`Logs`

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"WovPcbFdJ7e2755nwapZCG9gPXcBIouInBp6XwYDQio=", "sprofile"=>{"level_id"=>"1", "contact_no"=>"484-767-9853", "skill_ids"=>[""]}, "commit"=>"Update Sprofile", "id"=>"1"}
```